# Modular complex field is abelian?

Tags: complex-numbers

Lets define the set "modular Complex Set modulo prime" as the set of complex numbers {a+bi} (mod p) as {a (mod p) + b(mod p) i}. Is that an abelian group? I'm doing an on-line math course, and this is part of a discussion came up there in the comment-forum. I though that if a certain group is abelian group, such as the set of complex numbers, and we create a new group, by 1:1 mapping from the original one, then the resulting group is also abelian. The numbers a,b in {a+bi} are integers. So, I was not sure that my opinion is right, therefore asked this. The operation on the hypothetical group is comlex number multiplication. For instance: (3+4i)(4+2i) (mod 7) = (4+22i) mod 7 = 4+i, so the group low is complex multiplication.

Comment: I dunno, is it? (Okay, well, I know but whatever.) What have you tried? Where are you stuck? MSE generally prefers you include your own attempts and understanding of problems as opposed to dumping it at our feet and expecting we do the heavy lifting.

Comment: You should also specify the domain for $a,b$ (are they integers? reals?) and the operation on the hypothetical group (addition? multiplication? something else?).

Comment: Your group is called $\Bbb{C/(p Z+ipZ)}$ and it works quite the same way as $\Bbb{R/p Z}=\{ a \bmod p, a \in \Bbb{R}\}$. Do you see how the group law is defined on thatone ?